# Directing from JSP page to a servlet and back to the JSP results in a different JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

In my bank I have both managers and employees .

A manager is an employee , hence he (or she) has the same permissions of an employee .

I start from here : 
[image]

And Jacky chose that - an employee action :

[image]

Then I perform a regular registration that any employee does - as a manager :

[image]

And then I reach here :

[image]
[image]

Meaning , that this time I return as a manager to an **Employee page (!)** and not 
my own page - Manager's page .

So , the question is , how can I remember or know who clicked the "open new account" button , a manager or an employee ?

Note that the problem here is not a "normal" redirection , I can handle that : the problem is that I don't know who clicked the "open new account" button , since `2` people have that permission - a manager **and** an employee .

I can attach all the code , please say so if it is needed .

Regards

Comment: you can add a post parameter `&client=manager` or `&client=employee` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing that differentiates a manager-user from a employee-user then you can save a value in the session on the click of "Press here to continue" on the transaction page (e.g. "manager" for manager's and "employee" in employee's). And use that information to render the link on the Congratulations page.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a hidden tag in the html code. Set itz value to employee or manager in their respective pages.
Then in servlet you can save the value of the hidden field in a session variable.
thats how you can remember who clicked.